# PreferenceFragement does not set SharedPreferences until after PreferenceFragment is loaded

Tags: android, android-fragments, sharedpreferences, preferencefragment

The PreferenceFragment preferences are not being added to my SharedPreference Map until after I load the preference fragment.

1. Is this the intended behavior of the PreferenceFragment?
2. If so, what is the best way to apply all of the defaults specified in `preferences.xml` to the SharedPreferences even before the user visits the preference fragment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put `PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, false);` in the `onCreate()` function of the app's launcher activity to apply all of the defaults as soon as a user launches the app for the first time.

Comment: Thanks! One note: I had to uninstall the app for this to work because according to the DOCs, "`this method sets the default values only if this method has never been called in the past (or if the KEY_HAS_SET_DEFAULT_VALUES in the default value shared preferences file is false)`".

Comment: Huh, that's strange...So clearly the method had not ever been called in the past, so that means that KEY_HAS_SET_DEFAULT_VALUES must have been true somehow.  Weird, but glad it ended up working for you!

Comment: Oh wait, of course that key was set to true, as you had presumably loaded the PreferencesFragment before which would have set the defaults. So the reinstall makes sense. Not sure how I missed that :p